# ¿Cómo crear un tutorial de uso cuando un usuario ingresa a una aplicación web por primera vez?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, angular, web

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna libreria que me permita que la primera vez que entre un usuario a una web, le salga un tutorial de manejo de la misma. También digamos si el usuario le da clic en ayuda este mismo tutorial se despliegue. Esto asi como el estilo de estas librerias:
https://github.com/faruktoptas/FancyShowCaseView
https://github.com/sjwall/MaterialTapTargetPrompt

Agradezco si alguien sabe como se podría implementar esto

Comment: Hola Alejandra. Te invito a tomar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Tu pregunta es sumamente amplia y necesitamos ver qué código llevas hasta ahora y qué has intentado

Comment: Algo como [introjs](https://introjs.com/)?

Comment: Exacto Einer, gracias

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinión, no necesitas una librería para eso. Básicamente, si quieres que aparezca algo al un usuario que entra por primera vez, necesitas persistir esa información en una base de datos (o si no como sabes que el usuario ya visito antes). Seguro debes tener una tabla que incluye el nombre de usuario y su contraseña y otra información como nombre, etc. Ahí, también puedes incluir un flag como `HaVistoTutorial` que puede ser falso o verdadero. Una vez que se despliega (puedes crear una pagina de bienvenida con el enlace a la pagina del tutorial) por primera vez, el flag cambia a `true` (o 1) y así no se muestra nuevamente cuando el usuario regresa. Mi recomendación es que de todas maneras ofrezcas un enlace en su dashboard para que pueda entrar al tutorial cuando quiera. Ojala te sirva, disculpa el ingles pero solo trabajo programando en ingles.

Comment: lo ideal en estos casos es esperar a que ,la OP mejore su pregunta, pues solo pregunta como hacer algo pero no muestra ningún intento revisa por favor [ask]y tambien [answer]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario pero lo que pasa es que no quiero que sea un tutorial en otra pagina asi como lo dices sino mas bn algo mas interactivo como por asi decirlo modales que muestren paso a paso las funcionalidades.
En un comentario me comentaron acerca de esta herramienta y algo asi es lo que busco https://introjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hola tal vez no sea lo que necesitás pero te digo lo que hice yo una vez. 
Cree una variable COOKIE con php que por defecto sea 0, y cuando el usuario ingresa a cierta parte de la web le paso 1 a la cookie. Con tu tutorial podrías hacer lo mismo; la cookie por defecto es 0, y si el usuario entra por primera vez, la cookie será 1. Podrías

```
<?php $_COOKIE["primeravez"] = 0;

function entroalaweb(){
if($_COOKIE["primeravez"] == 0){
echo "Has ingresado por primera vez";
}else{
echo "Ya has ingresado anteriormente...";
$_COOKIE["primeravez"] = 1;
}
}
?>
```

Tal vez no sea lo que buscas pero capaz te sirve como idea.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad no busco codigo para si ingresa por primera vez, me respondieron que esto me puede servir https://introjs.com/